# Regarding map display in Uber iOS SDK

Tags: ios, uber-api

How can I display nearby Uber cabs while booking a ride using UBER iOS SDK widget?
Also, is it possible to display the live location tracking using UBER sdk?
please help...

Comment: Hey Neha, unfortunately the Uber API does not allow you to retrieve the location of nearby Uber partners. Sorry!

Comment: So is it not possible to show nearby cabs before booking a ride, as like in Google maps? In Google maps we can see the nearby cabs as like in Uber app's map.

Comment: Correct Neha-- that is not possible in our public. Google has a separate, private setup which is not generally available. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your support.